# Is it generally OK to ignore the current in and out of a MCU pin when analyzing circuit external to the MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, pins, pullup, pulldown

From [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pull-up-resistors/all), I see below illustration about the pull-up resistor.

[image]

And the article says:

> With a pull-up resistor, the input pin will read a high state when the
> button is not pressed. In other words, **a small amount of current is
> flowing between VCC and the input pin (not to ground), thus the input
> pin reads close to VCC**.

It gives me an impression that the current in and out of a MCU is so small that it can be ignored when analyzing the behavior of the circuit external to the MCU.

Such assumption may simplify things a bit. But is it OK?

Comment: An input pin usually has fairly high impedance. But it depends on how it is configured, too. If it is simply a digital input pin, it's likely that the input impedance is on the order of \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ or better (to both rails.)

Comment: @jonk It seems for a digital input pin, the higher the input impedance is the better.

Comment: The datasheet for the MCU will tell you a lot more detail. It's not hard to read one. And if you were asking (I cannot tell), then yes higher values (such as \$1\:\text{M}\Omega\$) is better.

Comment: @jonk Yes, I believe a datasheet can give me a specific value. But I just want to know why high input impedance is better. Is it because high input impedance can make the disturbance of connecting a MCU insignificant? Just more like nothing is connected.

Comment: Yeah. Infinite impedance would have zero interference. So big numbers are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. For values in K ohms usually you can ignore it, unless you're doing something with unusual operating environment or high reliability. It never hurts to read the datasheet thoroughly when you are considering spec'ing a new part though.

Of course if you enable internal pull-ups or pull-downs then you will generally have to take those into account.

If you try to minimize switch-closed consumption by using a resistor value like 10M then you will find that the MCU maker won't necessarily guarantee that will work.

For example, the Microchip ATMega328p has the following guaranteed characteristics:

[image]

1uA of leakage is enough to overcome the few hundred nA from the 10M resistor, so it might not work. Chances are the current will be much lower at Ta << 105°C so it might be okay for a toy or consumer device.

There are reasons not to use too low a resistor value (wasted power, possibly switch wear in extreme situations) and too high a value (switch reliability, leakage due to the semiconductors or contamination on the PCB and possible pickup of EMI).